# how to get bone location of edit mode?

Tags: python, animation, bones

I need to get bone's location in edit mode. Is it possible?
I found this, but it only works when I choose armature. I need to get bone's location without activating any armatures.

```
bpy.context.object.data.bones["BoneName"].head_local
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the [bone](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Bone.html#bpy.types.Bone) in the armature in `bpy.data` rather than in `bpy.context`.  The position of the head and the tail, relative to the parent are given as `head` and `tail`.  The positions relative to the armature are given by `head_local` and `tail_local`:

```
import bpy

armature = bpy.data.armatures['Armature']
bone = armature.bones['Bone']
head = bone.head
tail = bone.tail
head_local = bone.head_local
tail_local = bone.tail_local
```

Substitute the name of the armature you want for `'Armature'` in the first line and the name of the bone for `'Bone'` in the second line.

If you want world coordinates you have to transform the bone's local coordinates based on the position of the armature in world space.

Comment: it works fine. Thank you!